# OR argument matcher

Tags: googlemock

```
#include <vector>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

using namespace ::testing;
class A {
public:
    virtual void f(std::vector<int>& b, std::vector<int>& b1) { }
};
class AA : public A {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(f, void(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&));
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 3,2,1 };
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,3 };
    AA a;
    EXPECT_CALL(a, f(ContainerEq(v), ContainerEq(v1))).Times(1);
    // code will call f finally
    return 0;
}
```

The function `f` I mocked will passed in 2 vectors. However, the sequence may be random, v,v1 or v1,v are all correct. How to add an OR operator in EXPECT_CALL like:

```
EXPECT_CALL(a, f(ContainerEq(v) or ContainerEq(v1), ContainerEq(v1) or ContainerEq(v))).Times(1);
```

Does it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using `AnyOf`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(a, f(AnyOf(ContainerEq(v),ContainerEq(v1)),
                 AnyOf(ContainerEq(v),ContainerEq(v1)));
```

With C++11 or greater, you can also do the following:

```
auto matcher = AnyOf(ContainerEq(v),ContainerEq(v1));

EXPECT_CALL(a, f(matcher, matcher));
```